# RelativeLayout align Textview and Edittext

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, xamarin, xamarin-studio

I want to use a RelativeLayout to align horizontally a textview and after that an edittext and then again a textview and then an edittext. I know that you can do that with a LinearLayout, but I want to accomplish that with a relativeLayout.
My Code is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/userNameLbl"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Username:"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/userNameText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/userNameLbl"
        android:minWidth="200dp"
        android:text="Sample Text" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pwdLbl"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Password:"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/userNameText"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/userNameText" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/userNameText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/pwdLbl"
        android:minWidth="200dp"
        android:text="Sample Text" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

But it doesn't work. All the controls (**edittexts** and **textviews**) are put on each other! What is wrong with my code? I have used `layout_toRightOf` to put them next to each other.
And because it was mentioned, there is enough place for the controls.
Here is also a picture of the designer, how it is looking like:
[image]

Comment: use android:orientation="horizontal" in your layout

Comment: The reason is that your textviews and edittexts can't fit in one line. So you could use a HorizontalScrollView.

Comment: As a side note, I noticed you used 'toEndOf' for the one TextView, it's a good habit to use that for your EditTexts as well. Also, add 'alignParentStart=true' in the first one. This is all just to help support right-left layouts.

Comment: And, along with syntactic things, fill_parent is deprecated I would change that to 'match_parent'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the problem seems to be in Xamarin Studio itself which is not rendering the content of the layout correctly. Because when I run this layout on a device the controllers are put next to each other and there is not such a problem, but the designer show it completely different.

Answer (score 2):

I copied your code just to see the exact problem, but everything looked fine. However The last EditText was cramped on the right side due to space-issues.
Are you sure you have enough space so that everything can fit?

With too little space given it might be possible that the views get crammed onto each other.

Comment: I think this would be happening too. I can't test it, but the XML looks pretty good to me.

Comment: @Eomer I edited my question and pasted an image to show you the designer. There is definitely enough space for the controls.

Comment: @MoProg what kind of designer is that? I've never seen that. Have you tried running on a physical device?

Comment: @McAdam331 It is built via Xamarin Studio for Android. But you have been right. The problem is with the designer. When I run the application on a device, it is working correctly but the designer of Xamarin Studio is rendering it wrong

Comment: @MoProg well I'm glad it's working. Out of curiosity, why did you choose Xamarin Studio over Android Studio?

Comment: @McAdam331 Because I needed a framework where I could develope for both Android and IOS. With Xamarin I can share about 60 percent of the code between both platforms

Comment: @MoProg Gotcha. Well again, glad you're on the right track! I'd see if there's a way to report the bug to xamarin.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code it will align as you need:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/userNameLbl"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Username:" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/userNameText"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:minWidth="200dp"
            android:text="Sample Text" />




        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/pwdLbl"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Password:"

            />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/userNameText2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"


            android:minWidth="200dp"
            android:text="Sample Text" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment below if you need any further info

Comment: I don't think OP is going for a vertical group, but a horizontal one.

Comment: There is no screenshot provided, hence i have corrected the code to show in a standard way, as the screen is login screen , i feel it make sense to show username and password fields below one another

Comment: @Manikanta No I don't want to put the layouts below one another. But even with this code, when I run it I have the same problem and the controls in each layout are put on each other

Comment: So you want labels and text fields for username and password to be side by side?

Answer (score 0):

When you look closer, in `android:layout_toRightOf` and `android:layout_toEndOf` attributes you are using `@+id/...` values. Delete the `+` in order to refer to an existing resource item.

Comment: I don't think OP is going for a vertical group, but a horizontal one.

Comment: You are right, I reconsidered the question and edited the answer